# XSLT field names from Filemaker Pro

Tags: xml, xslt, filemaker

I'm new to XSLT and I'm trying to convert an XML file generated from Filemaker Pro using the fmpxmlresult grammar.
Filemaker outputs a RAW XML in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
   <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
   <PRODUCT BUILD="02-13-2018" NAME="FileMaker" VERSION="ProAdvanced 16.0.5" />
   <DATABASE DATEFORMAT="D/m/yyyy" LAYOUT="" NAME="fatture elettronica.fmp12" RECORDS="1" TIMEFORMAT="k:mm:ss " />
   <METADATA>
      <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="data" TYPE="DATE" />
      <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="ID" TYPE="TEXT" />
      <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="righe::descrizione" TYPE="TEXT" />
      <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="righe::prezzo" TYPE="TEXT" />
   </METADATA>
   <RESULTSET FOUND="1">
      <ROW MODID="1" RECORDID="1">
         <COL>
            <DATA>31/08/2018</DATA>
         </COL>
         <COL>
            <DATA>1</DATA>
         </COL>
         <COL>
            <DATA>patate</DATA>
            <DATA>pomodori</DATA>
            <DATA>uva</DATA>
         </COL>
         <COL>
            <DATA>100</DATA>
            <DATA>50</DATA>
            <DATA>70</DATA>
         </COL>
      </ROW>
   </RESULTSET>
</FMPXMLRESULT>
```

In my XSLT I select the fields using

```
<xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[1]/fmp:DATA"/>
```

It works but it's a little time confusing because I have a XML file with a lot of fields and it's easy to adress the wrong field by number.
Is there a way to select a field using the name of field that is listed in the metadata section?
I tried to search but I cannot even imagine the correct keywords to look for.
Thanks

Comment: Which version of XSLT does Filemaker support? Or do you use XSLT outside of Filemaker and have the choice to switch to an XSLT 2 or 3 processor like Saxon 9?

Comment: it supports version 1

Comment: Then it is rather difficult to find a compact expression, with XSLT 2 or 3 you could define your own function that returns the right index/position based on a name and then use e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="COL[mf:col-pos('ID')]/DATA"/>` instead of  `<xsl:value-of select="COL[2]/DATA"/>`, as I have done in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTzA. But with pure XSLT/XPath 1 you would need complex expressions like `<xsl:variable name="fields" select="//fmp:FIELD"/>`, `<xsl:value-of select="COL[count($fields[@NAME = 'ID']/preceding-sibling::fmp:FIELD) + 1]"/>`.

Comment: FileMaker's FMPXMLRESULT grammar was designed to allow field names to be changed without breaking the export. If you prefer to rely on field names rather than field order, use the FMPDSORESULT grammar when exporting - it will be much easier than what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a key to hold the field names and fetch the name from it by using the count function.

Something like this.

```
<!-- Define a key to get the first field and all fields that follow it by the field name -->
<xsl:key name="K" match="/fmp:FMPXMLRESULT/fmp:METADATA/fmp:FIELD" use="@NAME" />
<xsl:key name="K" match="/fmp:FMPXMLRESULT/fmp:METADATA/fmp:FIELD" use="following-sibling::fmp:FIELD/@NAME" />


<!-- Shortform to get a value for an attribute -->
<MyField  SomeAttr="{fmp:COL[count(key('K', 'SomeAttr'))]}"/>        

<!-- Format for getting a value for an element -->
<MyField>
    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[count(key('K', 'MyField'))]/fmp:DATA" />
</MyField>
```

This method also has the advantage that if you change your field export order in FileMaker, your XSLT will keep up. If you change the field name in FileMaker you just need to change the one statement in your XSLT where you fetch that field.

Comment: thanks I solved in a similar way:

`<xsl:variable name="mdf" select="/fmp:FMPXMLRESULT/fmp:METADATA/fmp:FIELD" />
<xsl:variable name="ID" select="count($mdf[following-sibling::fmp:FIELD/@NAME = 'ID']) + 1" />`
then I call the variable:
`<xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[$ID]/fmp:DATA"/>`

Comment: For a limited number of fields this approach could work. As you need to define a variable for each field, this method quickly becomes much work to maintain when you have dozens or hundreds of fields.

Answer (score 0):

In pure XSLT/XPath 1 it is difficult to find a compact expression, for instance to select the column where the corresponding `FIELD` has the `NAME` attribute value `ID`  you would need a complex select like `<xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[count($fields[@NAME = 'ID']/preceding-sibling::fmp:FIELD) + 1]/fmp:DATA"/>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fmp="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult"
    exclude-result-prefixes="fmp"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//fmp:ROW"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:variable name="fields" select="//fmp:FIELD"/>

  <xsl:template match="fmp:ROW">
    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[count($fields[@NAME = 'ID']/preceding-sibling::fmp:FIELD) + 1]/fmp:DATA"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTzA/2

In XSLT 2 or 3 you could define a function returning the index of the `FIELD` you want based on the `NAME` attribute value and have a compact `<xsl:value-of select="COL[mf:col-pos('ID')]/DATA"/>` expression:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:variable name="main-doc" select="/"/>

  <xsl:key name="field" match="FIELD" use="@NAME"/>

  <xsl:function name="mf:col-pos" as="xs:integer">
      <xsl:param name="field-name" as="xs:string"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="mf:col-pos($field-name, $main-doc)"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:function name="mf:col-pos" as="xs:integer">
      <xsl:param name="field-name" as="xs:string"/>
      <xsl:param name="field-anc" as="node()"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="key('field', $field-name, $field-anc)">
          <xsl:number/>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//ROW"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ROW">
     <xsl:value-of select="COL[mf:col-pos('ID')]/DATA"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks but unfortunately it gave me and error. I solved in this way:
`<xsl:variable name="mdf" select="/fmp:FMPXMLRESULT/fmp:METADATA/fmp:FIELD" />
<xsl:variable name="ID" select="count($mdf[following-sibling::fmp:FIELD/@NAME = 'ID']) + 1" />`
then I call the variable:
`<xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[$ID]/fmp:DATA"/>`

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way:

`<xsl:variable name="mdf" select="/fmp:FMPXMLRESULT/fmp:METADATA/fmp:FIELD" />
<xsl:variable name="ID" select="count($mdf[following-sibling::fmp:FIELD/@NAME = 'ID']) + 1" />`

then I call the variable:

```
<xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[$ID]/fmp:DATA"/>
```